# Is there a way to obtain author counts by importing a text bibliography into R?

Tags: import, bibliography, citations

A colleague of mine is creating a bibliography on a particular topic and is interesting in figuring out the relative contributions of each researcher to the field (in terms of paper number). Currently I think they are doing this by manually counting each entry, and they are unable to easily sort between conference abstracts versus full publications.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this in R? I.e., is there a way to upload a text bibliography, give it a known format to read the references in akin to an Endnote Style, and use that to extract the author list, journals and formats this research was published in, etc.? I think this is doable if the Bibliography is in Bibtex, but unfortunately my colleague is from an older generation and is not big into computers, so they have been doing this on a Microsoft Word document.